# Setting a field in a JSF page onload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'd like to set a field of a backing bean as the JSF page loads. How can I achieve this?

My Environment is JSF 2.2 + Primefaces 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it on page load, you can use `<p:remoteCommand>` with `autoRun="true"`

```
public void setSomeValue(String someValue) {
    ...
}
```

```
<p:remoteCommand autoRun="true" actionListener="#{myBean.setSomeValue('my value')}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it in `@PostConstruct` method of backing bean associated with the page.

E.g.

```
private String someField;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    someField = "someDefaultValue";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's surely a best practice, however in my case I'd need to set it from the xhtml page. It's an xhtml page generated from a Swing UI using a tool and I need to provide some defaults directly in the page.